# how to show horizontal scroll bar in empty kendo grid using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to show horizontal scroll bar in empty kendo grid using angularjs?. Displaying the kendo grid if there is no record it shows only column header without horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

At last  i found the solution for applying the horizontal scroll bar empty kendo grid using angularjs.

```js
dataBound: function () {

                if (this.dataSource.view().length == 0) {
                    //insert empty row
                    var colspan = this.thead.find("th").length;
                    var emptyRow = "<tr><td colspan='" + colspan + "'></td></tr>";
                    this.tbody.html(emptyRow);

                    //workarounds for IE lt 9
                    this.table.width(800);
                    $(".k-grid-content").height(2 * kendo.support.scrollbar());
                }
                else {
                    //To reset width and height once record filled in the grid
                    this.table.width('100%');
                    $(".k-grid-content").height('');
                }
}
```